# Will Google collect my data given I use Google Chrome with DuckDuckGo?

Tags: google-chrome, duckduckgo

I have recently change my default search engine to DuckDuckGo. But I still use the Google Chrome as my browser. Will Google still collect my data?

Comment: Google collects information through the use of browser cookies, if your logged into your Google account, Google will collect whatever information it normally collects because of those browser cookies

Comment: All DuckDuckGo does is prevent Google from tracking your searches. Nothing else.

Answer (score 5):

Changing only your search engine won't make a big difference all, if your aim is to stop Google from tracking all your online activity - using DuckDuckGo will prevent Google from tracking your exact searches, and as such giving you slightly more privacy.

However, almost ALL websites **(non-Google websites included)** nowadays have multiple Google trackers embedded in them, which you are unaware of. So in the end, just simply switching search engines won't make a HUGE difference. So Google no longer tracks just your searches, they track your cross-site activity too!

**For example, Google has 5 trackers on this website, SuperUser, so they have that data on you**

I would recommend using an extension like uBlock Origin, which will block most if not all Google trackers AND trackers from other sites (along with ads) and you should also disable cookies (unless a site requires them to work). Do this if you don't want to switch browsers.

I used to use Chrome, but switched to Firefox with DuckDuckGo for privacy, as Firefox has many inbuilt tracker blockers you can enable which are very effective. I also use uBlock Origin with Firefox too. It has a very similar interface to Chrome, and in my experience, is just as fast as Chrome AND uses less computer resources. If you use lots of extensions as well, Firefox does not have as large a library as Chrome, but all the popular ones are there and many others that are safe and privacy-focused.

So, simply changing search engines won't make a huge difference, but if you're not willing to change browsers I would 100% recommend the uBlock Origin extension. Otherwise, I would switch to Firefox and explore all the features they have there. I'm happy to answer any further questions you might have!